# Sharing data within Fragments in Tabs using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to send data to 3 other fragments in a Tab of 4 from the first Tab which gets the data from the server, but observing the creation of the `Tabbed Fragments`, First and Second is Initialized, so the second doesn't get the data and the third and fourth get it. Even, when I tried to load the data from `onResume` in the second `Fragment` Is there anyway I can let tell the `Second Fragment` should reload itself when the `Tab` is clicked. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you don't like the posted answers, I think a good idea is to post the related code. This way I can give concrete specific code examples.

Comment: Posting code wouldn't do any good if you know the steps to creating a SlidingTab which is a normal thing. So, my explanation is enough

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) would when you detect when the SecondFragment becomes active.

I would generally recommend notifying such things through the parent `Activity`